# Как заполнить массив в несколько потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть такой массив, знаю что нужно через Thread, а как делать не пойму. Нужно разбивать массив на части,  или можно сразу как-то сделать?

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                int[] a = new int[10000];
                Random rand = new Random();
    
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                {
                    a[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
                }
                foreach (var p in a)
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                stopWatch.Stop();
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);
                Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

Comment: Каждый цикл пусть заполняет какую-то часть массива. Например 100 элементов заполняют 4 потока. Первый поток заполняет первые 25 элементов, второй следующие и т.д.

Comment: Ваша, на первый взгляд, несложная задача имеет немало подводных камней. Например, класс Random непотокобезопасный. Поэтому нужен собственный экземпляр для каждого потока. А там может возникнуть проблема [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). Поэтому очень рекомендую  [Patterns for Parallel Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) - это большая статья (или даже небольшая книга). Там есть раздел про правильное заполнение массивов в отдельных потоках.

Comment: Для количества элементов порядка тысячи распараллеливать запись не имеет смысла: запуск потоков и синхронизация отнимут намного больше времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом примере я делю массив на блоки по 4000 байтов (1000 элементов) каждый и работаю с каждым блоком в отдельном потоке.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
var array = new int[10000];
var offsets = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select( x => x * 1000 );
Parallel.ForEach( offsets, offset => {
    for ( int i=0; i<1000; i++ )
    {
        array[offset + i] = random.Next( -100,100 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Ещё раз: класс Random не является потокобезопасным. В результате метод Next может начать выдавать одно и то же значение.

Comment: Я понимаю, но задача стояла конкретно такая.

Comment: Если задача состоит в том, чтобы заполнить массив случайными числами, то вы не выполнили её. Числа могут оказаться одинаковыми, а именно: 0. Как повезёт.

Comment: Работа _с массивом_ в нескольких потоках сделана правильно. Тут претензий нет.